# How can "in a way that is similar to that of" be shortened?

Tags: phrase-requests

Originally the text was:

> Energy is delivered to the charging system similar to that during
>   normal power operation.

I came up with the following solution:

> Energy is delivered to the charging system in a way that is similar to
>   that of normal power operation.

But it still seems awkward and clunky so please let me know if it's acceptable and provide some suggestions for alternative ways to word this phrase.

Comment: Check out the English language learners’ stack exchange

Comment: Based on two of the answers so far I can see normal power operation being used as a countable noun. Normal power operation isn't a thing. It's not an apple. It's a state like decomposition. So using "a normal power operation" is like saying "The apple lays on the ground in a state of a decomposition." So what I'm looking for is something more along the lines of "The apple breaks down in the stomach in a way that is similar to that of decomposition." Decomposition is normal and it's being compared to an abnormal operational mode.

Comment: It's the word "operation" that is countable.

Comment: "kinda like when using"

Comment: Operation: n. The state of being operative or functional: a factory in operation.
You can't say "a factory in an operation" without changing the meaning

Comment: "Energy delivery to the system during charging differs little from the method used during normal power operation."

Answer (score 2):

***[à la](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_la)*** (ODO)

> **1.1** *informal* In the style or manner of.
>   ‘afternoon talk shows à la Oprah’

However, in the given formal context,

[***as***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as) ODO

> **2** Used to indicate by comparison the way that something happens or is done.
>   *‘The direction deserves commendation, **as** do all the actors.’*

"Energy is delivered to the charging system **as** in a normal power operation."
should be more elegant and appropriate.

Comment: I would upvote this if it led with your real suggestion, instead of giving pride of both space and place to a suggestion that you seem to recognize is inappropriate.

Comment: @ruakh I know. Free of context, "in a way that is similar to that of " can only be conveniently expressed as  *à la* which would be the correct answer, but for the very formal context. The OP made no express mention of context type.

Comment: That is correct. It's too formal to use à la but it's still good to know about it because it increases my personal expressive ability.

Comment: I think "as" works as well but what about "like"?

Comment: Do you think "as in" has any words omitted? As in "as it does in". I've noticed there are numerous phrases in English where certain words are dropped if they're not completely necessary for disambiguation.

Comment: *As* itself has a complete meaning of "the way that something is done," which should be enough for the purpose.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not as simple as it sounds. As for using "as", it's used as much as people like as long as it works. At which point it doesn't exactly have a complete meaning of the way that something is done.
Origin
Middle English: reduced form of Old English alswā ‘similarly’ (see also).
I'm not saying it's a bad choice, but on it's own it might not be enough.

Comment: At this stage I really wish I could just simply use à la

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you don't view this question as being an off-topic request for writing advice.

Answer (score 1):

> "…*[in the same way](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-same-way)* as **a** normal power operation."

or

> "…*[pretty much like](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pretty-much)* a normal…"

or

> …[in a similar way](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/in%20a%20similar%20way) **to** a…

Sources: *Collins Dictionary* and *Vocabulary.com*

Comment: +1 I realized after I posted my own answer that it made use of one of your suggested phrase changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lack of context that would make this this completely clear.

You say:

> Energy is delivered to the charging system in a way that is similar to that of normal power operation.

So, I'm assuming the greater context is the delivery of energy during an *abnormal* situation. For the sake of argument, let's say it's an emergency situation.

The sentence itself could be shortened in several ways. It's not just the phrase you've singled out that can be simplified, but other sentence elements too.

> Emergency power is delivered in the same way as normal power.